# Позиционирование элемента CSS

Tags: позиционирование, css

Есть изображение. Как спозиционировать крестик (Х) в правый верхний угол изображения? Пропорции картинки могут быть разными.

Comment: Какая примерно структура html? Есть ли у картинки "обёртка" в виде блочного элемента? Только CSS или можно ещё JS?

Comment: Обёртка есть блоком div. Можно и JS

Answer (score 3):

Просто через абсолютное позиционирование относительно родителя картинки.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.img-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.img-wrapper .close-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.img-wrapper .close-link:hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.85);
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="close-link">&#215;</a>
  <img src="http://elitefon.ru/images/201302/elitefon.ru_32715.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
for(var i=0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('image').length; i++)
{
    document.getElementsByClassName('del')[i].style.marginLeft = document.getElementsByClassName('image')[i].offsetWidth-16 + 'px';
}
```

```html
<span class="image">
    <a class="del" href="" style="position: absolute;">x</a>
    <img src="" width="80" height="80" alt="" />
</span>

<span class="image">
    <a class="del" href="" style="position: absolute;">x</a>
    <img src="" width="80" height="80" alt="" />
</span>

<span class="image">
    <a class="del" href="" style="position: absolute;">x</a>
    <img src="" width="80" height="80" alt="" />
</span>
```

Comment: Брррррр.. Зачем тут скрипт??

Answer (score 0):

[Вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/RkfuV/)

Comment: Пишите более развернутые комментарии. Ссылки могут устареть.

Comment: да, и ваш вариант не работает в Сафари на маке – http://joxi.ru/vAWYJ7YiVlK6mW

Comment: В хроме в Windows он тоже не работает...

Comment: Да и в Linux тоже не работает

Answer (score -1):

```
float:right;
vertical-align:top;
```

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете вы так: 

    <img><div style="float:right; vertical-align:top;">x</div></img>

?!

Comment: Не совсем. У Вас же картинка то же лежит в чем то? например в <a></a>.
Вот и рядом с картинкой вставьте ещё дивчик, а ему эти свойства.
Пример <a href=""><img src="" /><div style="float:right; vertical-align:top;">X</div></a>

Comment: Не сработает же. Точнее, при добавлении отрицательных margin'ов сработать может, но в ответе про это ни слова.