# Как при наведении мышкой на фотку отобразить на ней ссылку?

Tags: javascript, ссылки

Есть фотка и ссылка. Как при наведении мышкой на фотку отобразить на ней ссылку и чтоб она работала?

```
     <table id="product">
         <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="<?=$this->product["img"]?>" alt="<?=$this->product["title"]?>" />
            <a id="zum" href="<?=$this->product["img"]?>" rel="thumbnail">УВЕЛИЧИТЬ</a>
        </td>
                <td>
                ...
                </td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

**Обновление**

Стили есть, ссылка поверх фотки - с этим проблем нет. Вот нужно при наведении на фотку чтобы ссылка появлялась и по ней можно было кликнуть, а когда мышку забрать, то ссылка пропадала, а фотка оставалась в первоночальном состоянии, то есть осталась только фотка без ссылки.

Comment: стили есть ссылка поверх фотки с этим проблем нет, вот нужно при наведении на фотку штоб ссылка появлялась и по ней можно было кликнуть, а когда мышку забрать то ссылка пропадала а фотка оставалась в первоночальном состоянии, тоесть осталась только фотка без ссылки.

Comment: @jobananas, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244730/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-css/244759

Answer (score 1):

Оберните картинку и ссылку в див и присвойте ему какой-нибудь класс. В моем примере у него класс wrap. По дефолту скройте картинку в стилях и спозиционируйте ее, например, внизу дива. При наведении на обертку показывайте ссылку.

Пример кода:

```
.wrap{position: relative;}
.link{position: absolute; display: none; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; background: #fff;}
.wrap:hover .link{display: block;}
```

Классы элементов смените на свои.

Comment: у меня стили есть сам механизм, чтоб ссылки не было, когда фото без фокуса, а когда с фокусом, чтоб появлялась и можно было по ней кликнуть, желательно описать в моём варианте примера, скорее всего, нужно подменять содержимое ячейки с помощью js, но как это правильно сделать

Comment: Не совсем понял вас. Распишите подробнее ваше первое предложение. И js тут, вероятнее всего, не нужен

Comment: смотрите, у меня в ячейке сейчас находятся фотка и ссылка, нужно чтоб изначально ссылки не было видно, а при наведении была фотка и ссылка и чтоб ссылка была кликабельной. У меня стили есть, всё выстроено правильно просто нужно, чтоб скрыть и показать ссылку, а у вас со стилями написано.

Comment: Всё ок правильно работает спасибо большое ставлю люкс

Comment: Я привел рабочее и, вероятнее всего, оптимальное решение. Чем оно вас не устраивает? Подобная задача решается чаще всего с помощью css. Вы либо не полностью освещаете свою проблему, либо, не знаю, не очень грамотно пишете, поэтому я вас не понимаю.

Comment: ответ был дан в сообщение выше!

Comment: прошу щитать тему закрытой